# Prove that the convergence of the sequence (s3n) implies the convergence of (sn).

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I write $s_n-s$, as $(s_n^3-s^3)/(s_n^2+s_n*s+s^2)$, true for all $n>N$. 
I'm trying to show that the denominator is convergent. 
But I don't know how to do this.
Need help! Thanks. (Sorry about the confusion in the previous question I posted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $a \neq 0$. So if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n^3 = a^3$, then we show $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = a$. Since  $S_n^2 + a\cdot S_n + a^2 = \left( S_n + \dfrac{a}{2} \right)^2 + \dfrac{3a^2}{4} \geq \dfrac{3a^2}{4}$, we have: $|S_n - a| = \dfrac{|S_n^3 - a^3|}{|S_n^2 + a\cdot S_n + a^2|} \leq \dfrac{4\cdot |S_n^3 - a^3|}{3a^2}$. To complete the proof, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that if $n > N$ then $|S_n^3 - a^3| < \dfrac{3\epsilon\cdot a^2}{4}$. So $|S_n - a| < \epsilon$ and we're done.

Case 2: $a = 0$. Then for a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that if $n > N$ then $|S_n^3 - 0| < \epsilon^3$ then $|S_n| < \epsilon$. Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f\colon x\mapsto \sqrt[3]x$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ so since the sequence $\left(s_n^3\right)_n$  is convergent to say $s$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(s_n^3\right)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n^3\right)=f(s)=\sqrt[3]s$$